# Implementing ls commands in c

Tags: c, linux, shell, segmentation-fault, ls

I am struggling with my code. I need to implement `ls`, `ls -l`, `ls -i`, and `ls -R` commands in my C program. So far I only did `ls -l`, `ls -i`, and `ls -R` as I am not sure how to implement `ls` because there is no argument. The challenge is also that after executing the program, use should be able to type `% myls -l` and get the results as for command `ls -l`.

Also right now I get Segmentation error 11 :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

DIR * dir;
struct dirent * ptr;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
// declaration for different parameters

void _l(char *direct);
void _i(char *direct);
void _R(char *direct);

// get the argc[]
char para[20];
char direct[100];
memset(direct, 0, sizeof(direct));
// copy the parameter like -l
strcpy(para, argv[1]);
// copy the path like ./
strcpy(direct, argv[2]);

// call the corresponding function according to parameters

if (strcmp(para, "-l") == 0)
{
    _l(direct);
}
if (strcmp(para, "-i") == 0)
{
    _i(direct);
}
   if (strcmp(para, "-R") == 0)
{
    _R(direct);
}


}


void _l(char *direct)
{
void mode_to_letter(int mode, char *str);
// define struct stat
struct stat fst;
struct tm * mytime = (struct tm *) malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
char str[12];
dir = opendir(direct);
// skip . and ..
readdir(dir);
readdir(dir);
while((ptr = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    stat(ptr->d_name, &fst);
    // permission information
    mode_to_letter(fst.st_mode, str);
    // file type and permission
    printf("%s", str);
    // file hard links
    printf(" %d", fst.st_nlink);
    // file's owner
    printf(" %s", getpwuid(fst.st_uid)->pw_name);
    // file's owner group
    printf(" %s", getgrgid(fst.st_gid)->gr_name);
    // file size
    printf(" %ld", (long)fst.st_size);
    // file time
    mytime = localtime(&fst.st_mtime);
    printf(" %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d", mytime->tm_year + 1900, mytime->tm_mon + 1, mytime->tm_mday, mytime->tm_hour, mytime->tm_min);
    // file name
    printf(" %s", ptr->d_name);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void mode_to_letter(int mode, char *str)
{
str[0] = '-';

// judge file type
if(S_ISDIR(mode)) str[0] = 'd';
if(S_ISCHR(mode)) str[0] = 'c';
if(S_ISBLK(mode)) str[0] = 'b';

// judge permission for owner
if(mode & S_IRUSR) str[1] = 'r';
else str[1] = '-';
if(mode & S_IWUSR) str[2] = 'w';
else str[2] = '-';
if(mode & S_IXUSR) str[3] = 'x';
else str[3] = '-';

// judge permission for owner group
if(mode & S_IRGRP) str[4] = 'r';
else str[4] = '-';
if(mode & S_IWGRP) str[5] = 'w';
else str[5] = '-';
if(mode & S_IXGRP) str[6] = 'x';
else str[6] = '-';

// judge permission for others
if(mode & S_IROTH) str[7] = 'r';
else str[7] = '-';
if(mode & S_IWOTH) str[8] = 'w';
else str[8] = '-';
if(mode & S_IXOTH) str[9] = 'x';
else str[9] = '-';

str[10] = '\0';
}

void _i(char *direct)
{
dir = opendir(direct);
readdir(dir);
readdir(dir);
while((ptr = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    // get inode id
    printf("%ld ", (long)ptr->d_ino);
    printf("%s\n", ptr->d_name);
}
closedir(dir);
}



void _R(char *direct)
{
dir = opendir(direct);

while((ptr = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    // skip . and ..
    if(!strcmp(ptr->d_name,".") || !strcmp(ptr->d_name,".."))
        continue;
    // if directory
    if (ptr->d_type & DT_DIR)
    {
        printf("%s: \n", ptr->d_name);
        // do recursively
        _R(ptr->d_name);
    }
    else
        // print the name
        printf("%s ", ptr->d_name);
 }
}
```

Comment: "*.. I am not sure how to implement ls because there is no argument..*" Huh? Which argument? How is it different from `ls -l`?

Comment: ls just displays the folders and files, and ls -l displays it with time, file permissions, and etc...

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: That is the assignment that i need to implement:( ls and ls -l, ls -i, ls -R.

Comment: But my main concern right now is Segmentation error. Do you know what I am doing wrong here? When I compile it doesnt give me any more information, just that: Segmentation fault:11

Comment: `argc` will tell you how many arguments there are (plus one for the program name). Use that to determine whether you should check `argv[1]` or simply just do an `ls`. Right now you copy from `argv[1]` without checking whether it's initialized.

Comment: Should I use 2 argc then? one will be for ls, and 2 for ls -l?

Comment: Write a program that prints the values of `argv[]` in a loop limited by `argc`.

Comment: Compile your program with debugging symbols enabled (add `-g` everytime you run the compiler), then load the program into the debugger and run it. It should give you a hint as to why you are getting the error.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the first argument (program name, `ls`), `[1]` is the second argument (`-l`), `[2]` is the third argument (path), etc.  `argc` is the number of arguments. So `argv[argc-1]` is your last argument.

Comment: So i need to add this `strcpy(para, argv[0]);` right?

Comment: Do i need to create void for just ls?

Comment: The information, regarding time, permissions, etc can be acquired through `stat` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Comment: When you run `myls -l` the value of `argc` is 2 and `argv[2]` is `NULL`. I bet when you run `myls -l /tmp` it will not `SEGFAULT`.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking the contents of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` without checking whether `argv` is long enough to have them. If they are not present, this results in a segfault. The length of `argv` is passed as `argc`. One simple fix for that (and to call a function for a plain `ls`) would be:

```
if (argc == 1) {
    _noarg(); // implement this function for a plain "ls"
} else {
    char para[20];
    char direct[100];
    memset(direct, 0, sizeof(direct));
    // copy the parameter like -l
    strcpy(para, argv[1]);
    if (argc > 2) {
        // copy the path like ./
        strcpy(direct, argv[2]);
    }
    // ... your other if statements that
    // call corresponding functions go here
}
```

Then make sure you check whether `direct` is NULL in your `_l`, `_i`, and `_R` functions before reading from it, as this will also cause a segfault. If it is NULL, you'll want to use the current directory instead.

Comment: When I did that i get these errors: `new2.c:41:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'para'
    if (strcmp(para, "-l") == 0)
               ^
new2.c:43:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'direct'
        _l(direct);`

Comment: I also get this warning: `new2.c:28:9: warning: implicit declaration of function '_noarg' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        _noarg(); //this function will run for a plain "ls"`

Comment: You need to create the function like you did `_l`, `_i`, and `_R`. You can name it whatever you want, I just picked `_noarg`

Comment: So it is like that `void _noarg();` right? and this is `if (strcmp(para, " ") == 0)
    {
        _noarg();
    }`

Comment: do i leave para blank, right because we dont have any?

Comment: Also do you think once if fix it, I wont have a segmentation error 11?

Comment: Yes, it's void. You don't need that if strcmp statement though for _noarg. _noarg just gets called before even looking at para or anything because if argc is 1 then there are no extra arguments to look at. You may have other errors later, I didn't look too closely, but that will fix the segfault from looking at `argv` without checking `argc`

Answer (score 1):

Your `SEGAFULT` is caused by passing `NULL` to `_l(direct)`, `_i(direct)` and `_R(direct)`.

To fix this issue you can test if `path` is passed or not by changing this line from:

```
strcpy(direct, argv[2]);
```

To:

```
if(argc < 3) // checks if path is passed or not
    strcpy(direct,"."); //if path is not passed, then work on cwd
else
    strcpy(direct, argv[2]); //otherwise the path is stored in argv[2]
```

Now your `SEGFAULT` is gone. This is assuming you don't implement the `ls` command yet. If you do, then you need to test `argv[1]` for path instead of `argv[2]` when there isn't `-l`, `-i`, nor `-R`.

It must also be noted that `readdir(direct)` returns a pointer to struct whose struct member name is relative to `direct`. This means that `stat(ptr->d_name, &fst);` will fail to get the stat of a path. To resolve this issue you need to change this line:

```
stat(ptr->d_name, &fst);
```

To

```
char filename[127];
sprintf(filename, "%s/%s", direct, ptr->d_name);
stat(filename, &fst);
```

This will allow `stat()` to get the stat of the file's full path.